# Android Unknown Host Exception (DNS Problem) !

Tags: android, dns

i'm trying to connect to the server from my android device in order to get XML inputStream to do that i'm using XmlPullParser

my server Url is: 
http://www.biat.com.tn

so, when i'm trying to get the inputstream from this url, I'm getting an unknown host Exception, the screen become black... (although it works for me in localhost)

Then, to check my config I tried to ping the server from the ADB shell, but there is no connection established !!!
I check an other server (http://www.topnet.tn), but i faced the same problem.

**PS : I'm getting Streams from these URLs in Navigator**

I think that .TN (Tunisia) domain name are not known by Android devices !!!!

i googled this problem and I found a solution, that i should lauch my application in -dns-server mode with putting 8.8.8.8 as dns server... so it works

but pinging my URL server does not !!! please any one can understand this problem !!!

please help...

Comment: Does your code work if you give it an url like google.com?

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the data? URLConnection, HttpClient?

`http://www.biat.com.tn` does http 302 redirect to `http://www.biat.com.tn/biat/`.

In most cases you will need to handle redirect in your code.

Comment: I'm loading it with URLConnection to get the inputStream and then parse it with xmlPullParser, my complete URL is  http://www.biat.com.tn/biat/simulator_mobile.jsp and i put it in the code but nothing happened !!!!